# How to continue HTML5 live stream video and audio after internet interruption?

Tags: javascript, html, streaming

HTML5 live stream stops permanently when internet is disconnected for a short or long time. How can we continue stream when internet is working again? Is there any reconnect event in JS that we can use?

```html
<video id="audiox" style="display:none;"controls="" autoplay="auto" name="media"><source id="audiovb" preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://sirius.shoutca.st:8237/stream" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
```